# Five figures are coded with symbols, find the code for Fig. 1

Tags: pattern, explanation

[image]

There are 5 figures shown on the top With their code written at the bottom of each figure, We need to find the code for fig.1

Source: UCEED 2016 question paper (entrance exam for design colleges in India)

The answer is B. Can someone please explain the logic behind it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the symbols in the provided strings

> encodes a property of the corresponding figure:
>  Sun: contains a rounded box
>  Drop: contains multiple filled circles (?)
>  Knot: contains five objects
>  Zigzags: contains four objects that aren't shapes (?)
>  Yin-Yang: contains a triangle
>  X in Box: contains no empty shapes
>  Since Fig. 1 doesn't have a rounded box, the answer is either B or D, and since Fig. 1 has more than five objects, D is out.
>  (Justifying that B is correct requires a strict definition of "shape" as either a circle, rounded box, or *regular* polygon, else the four lines could instead be two 45-45-90 triangles.)

Comment: Actually, only the knot is necessary to know it's answer B ;)

Comment: Got it, Thanks!

Comment: @Lezzup I didn't figure out what Knot represented until I was just about finished writing this answer, so my initial solve path was "Zigzag-and-not-Sun".

Comment: I had zig-zag: contains parallel lines.

Comment: Another solution path: Assuming symbols are properties, A and C are equivalent, so cannot be the answer.  Since the zig-zag is almost everywhere, it is probably correct.  The answer must be B.

Comment: @FlorianF I follow you in eliminating A and C, but the knot is exactly as "almost everywhere" as the zig-zag is, so we have to puzzle out what at least one of those symbols means to make the decision between B and D.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Indeed!  I didn't notice that.  It seems we have to actually figure out the symbols after all.